# jQuery pass variable from one function to another

Tags: jquery, function, variables

I am trying to take a variable that is set in one function and pass it to another to perform a calculation with it, but can't get it to work.

```
//Tier Selection Cost Setting
  $("input[type='radio'][name='tier-selected']").on("change", function() {
    var tierCost = ($("input[type='radio'][name='tier-selected']:checked").val());
    return tierCost;
    });

  //Residential Form Calcs
  $('#residential-apartment-number, #residential-floor-number, #residential-basement-number').on('keyup', function() {
    //Residential Form Variables
    var residentailApartmentNumber = $("#residential-apartment-number").val();
    var residentialFloorNumber = $("#residential-floor-number").val();
    var residentialBasementNumber = $("#residential-basement-number").val();
    //Calculations
    var averageDoors = residentailApartmentNumber / residentialFloorNumber;
    var numberOfElevators = averageDoors / 6;
    var numberOfColumns = residentialFloorNumber / 20;
    var totalElevators = Math.ceil(numberOfColumns) * Math.ceil(numberOfElevators);
    var elevatorCost = totalElevators * tierCost
    alert(elevatorCost);
  });
```

I am trying to use the variable `tierCost` that is set in the first function, and pass it into the second function to be used in the final line of that function for calculation purposes.

All lines in the calculation function as intended, and the first function does set `tierCost` to the correct value, but when I run it and input the numbers from the form, it returns NaN.

If I replace `tierCost` with a number in the calculation, everything works, and if `tierCost` is alerted from the first function, it sets the proper number, so as far as I can tell, my error is in getting the variable from one function to the other.

Comment: `tierCost` is a local variable, and not accessible outside that first anonymous on change function. You could either make it global (declare var `tierCost` outside the function--which would be a kludge, not recommended) or better yet why not just replace `var elevatorCost = totalElevators * tierCost` with `var elevatorCost = totalElevators * $("input[type='radio'][name='tier-selected']:checked").val()`?

Comment: @kmoser I'd suggest making that an answer

Comment: @kmoser yes this works. I was trying to have it set outside of the function as a variable that i could use because it will be needed in other forms that i have yet to build, but if i have to print it in every form to make it work then so be it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you've got is the two functions have no relationship to one another; they are separate callbacks to different events.

`tierCost` is set as a locally-scoped variable in the change callback, so nothing outside of that can read it (in fact, this would cause an error in the console when your second, keyup callback runs).

You're trying to return it from the change callback, but to nothing, since return values from events don't go anywhere (except to sometimes suppress the event).

Instead, set the tier cost info to a variable acccessible outside the callbacks.

```
let tierCost = 0;

$("input[type='radio'][name='tier-selected']").on("change", function() {
    tierCost = $("input[type='radio'][name='tier-selected']:checked").val();
});
```

(Note also it's better these days to use `let` not `var`).

Comment: Note calculation using `tierCost` will return NaN if no radio selected

Comment: Good spot. Meant to set initial value of 0.

Comment: @charlietfl @Mitya In the form itself, there is a default radio selected, so that wouldn't be the issue, I just didn't post it as i didn't think it was relevant, sorry. I tried this in my code however and it still doesn't set the ```tierCost``` outside of the first function, it just uses the value of "0".

Comment: In that case the change callback is not happening before the keyup callback.